# Executing mysqli_query inside a function

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a list of functions in **functions.php**.  I'm upgrading from *Mysql* to *Mysqli* because I just learning *Mysql* is now depreciated.

I declare my connection in a top levelconnect.php file. The first file is required.

All my functions use `mysql_query("QUERY")`, which always worked fine. Now I changed all of them to:

```
$con->query("QUERY") // ($con is my connection variable)
```

Now I'm getting a

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\PHP\functions.php on line 241

I don't get why I can query if I'm declaring my variable in my whole file. It should be accessible everywhere, I'm just not sure. This has put my website on hold until I can fix this. Here is a sample function from **functions.php**

```
function getSiteName()
{
    $row = $con->query("SELECT * FROM siteinfo")->fetch_array();
    return $row["siteName"];
}
```

My connection:

```
global $con ;
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "itunes89", "XXXX","projectanvil") or die("Sorry, were having server connection issues. Please try again later.");
```

Comment: What is `$con`? Where did you declare it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's a [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) problem. You need to pass `$conn` to `getSiteName()`:

```
function getSiteName($con) {
    $row = $con->query("SELECT * FROM siteinfo")->fetch_array();
    return $row["siteName"];
}

$name = getSiteName($con);
```

Or using a class with constructor injection:

```
class MyThing
{
    protected $con;

    public function __construct($con) {
        $this->con = $con;
    }

    public function getSiteName() {
        $row = $this->con->query("SELECT * FROM siteinfo")->fetch_array();
        return $row["siteName"];
    }
}

$obj = new MyThing($con);
$name = $obj->getSiteName();
```

Throughout the class you can use `$this->con` to access the connection.

Answer (score -1):

Since you made $con global, to make getSiteName function access it you should write:

```
 function getSiteName(){
 global $con;
      $row = $con->query("SELECT * FROM siteinfo")->fetch_array();
      return $row["siteName"];
 }
```